# order list of tuples in revlex

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am trying to generate the list of all k tuples on the numbers 0 through n-1, but I want this list to be ordered in revlex. For example,

```
import itertools
list(itertools.combinations(range(0, 6), 3))
```

outputs these tuples in lexicographic ordering:

[(0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 3), (0, 1, 4), (0, 1, 5), (0, 2, 3), (0, 2, 4), (0, 2, 5), (0, 3, 4), (0, 3, 5), (0, 4, 5), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 2, 5), (1, 3, 4), (1, 3, 5), (1, 4, 5), (2, 3, 4), (2, 3, 5), (2, 4, 5), (3, 4, 5)]

whereas I would like the output to be ordered by reverse lexicographic:

[(0,1,2), (0,1,3), (0,2,3), (1,2,3), (0,1,4), (0,2,4), (1,2,4), (0,3,4), (1,3,4), (2,3,4), (0,1,5), (0,2,5), (1,2,5), (0,3,5), (1,3,5), (2,3,5), (0,4,5), (1,4,5), (2,4,5), (3,4,5)]

Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain "reverse lexicographic" in words or a mathematical formula? Your ordering of your example is not clear, at least not to me.

Comment: We say (a_1, ..., a_k) > (b_1, ..., b_k) in reverse lexicographic (revlex) if rightmost nonzero entry of the difference  (a_1 - b_1, ..., a_k - b_k) is negative. In the example above,  (1,2,3) > (0,1,4) by looking at the last entry of these tuples, 3 - 4 =-1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reverse lexicographic order sorts by last item, then next-to-last, etc. One way to do that is to take the range, reverse that range, use itertools to make all combinations from that, reverse each item in that combinations list, then finally reverse the overall list. A list or tuple can be reversed by slicing with `[::-1]`, so the reversal of `mylist` is `mylist[::-1]`. Using this, we can get one complicated expression

```
[i[::-1] for i in itertools.combinations(range(6)[::-1],3)][::-1]
```

The `range` function has a built-in way to get a decreasing sequence. If we use that, we get

```
[i[::-1] for i in itertools.combinations(range(5,-1,-1),3)][::-1]
```

which does not look any easier. Either of those expressions give the result

```
[(0, 1, 2),
 (0, 1, 3),
 (0, 2, 3),
 (1, 2, 3),
 (0, 1, 4),
 (0, 2, 4),
 (1, 2, 4),
 (0, 3, 4),
 (1, 3, 4),
 (2, 3, 4),
 (0, 1, 5),
 (0, 2, 5),
 (1, 2, 5),
 (0, 3, 5),
 (1, 3, 5),
 (2, 3, 5),
 (0, 4, 5),
 (1, 4, 5),
 (2, 4, 5),
 (3, 4, 5)]
```

which is what you want.

There are routines that can do this, and you could break up that expression into multiple lines with intermediate variables. Either would be more clear than that expression. The multiple lines could be:

```
r = range(6)[::-1]
c = itertools.combinations(r, 3)
l = [i[::-1] for i in c]
rl = l[::-1]
```

Now the variable `rl` holds your desired list.

All this was tested in Python 2.7.12. In Python 3 you probably need to put a `list()` around `r`.

Comment: Thank you very much! this is exactly what I was looking for.